# How many composite functions from $(f \circ f)(1) = 2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Let $F$ be sets of all functions from $S$ to $S$.

How many $f\in F$ are there so that $(f \circ f)(1) = 2$ ?

How I see it, is through a diagram and so that there is $4*4*4*4$ ways for the first  $f$ to make all of it's outputs and then there is $4$ to connect these outputs to $2$ because either $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ arrows must connect to $2$.

So $4^4*4$ is the answer?

Comment: There are only $4^4$ functions from $S\to S$.

Comment: If we write $a = f(1)$, then we have two restrictions: (1) $a \neq 1$ for otherwise $f(f(1)) = f(1) = 1$. (2) $f(a) = f(f(1)) = 2$. Outside the set $\{1, a\}$ you have freedom to choose the values of $f$. So there are $3 \times 4^2$ choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan Diego Rojas' answer preceded mine.

I agree with Juan Diego Rojas' reasoning.  Since the OP asked for a count of the number of functions, I will piggyback off of Juan's reasoning.

If f(1) = 2, then f(2) must = 2.  There are $4^2$ functions that will do this (i.e. f(3) can be anything and f(4) can be anything).

If f(1) = 3, then f(3) must = 2.  Again there are $4^2$ functions.
If f(1) = 4, then f(4) must = 2.  Again there are $4^2$ functions.

So the total number of satisfying functions is $3\times 4^2 = 48.$

Comment: I don't understand what does $4^2$ mean here?

Comment: $4^2 = 4 x 4 = 16.$

Comment: Obviously but I mean I don't get the logic , what is $4^2$ ?

Comment: @user1925052 in the case where f(1) = 2 and f(2) = 2, the choices for f(3) and f(4) are _unrestricted._  In such a circumstance, there are 4 choices for f(3) and **independently** 4 choices for f(4).  Therefore, the number of satisfying functions that have f(1)=2 and f(2)=2 is 4x4=16.

Answer (score 3):

By no means, since $|S^S| = 4^4$. 
Hint: You need that $f(f(1)) = 2$. We only need to restrict a value of the function $f(1) = k \in \{2,3,4\}$, because, if $f(1) = 1$, then $f(f(1)) = 1$.